# edit only selected radio buttons

Tags: php, radio-button

I have a table that stores category_id, top news etc fields.The top news field uses a radio button. I need to update values of radio button from database. I am able to retrieve value of top news of single category id while editing. When I try to multiple edit the category id then I am only getting value of single top news from database and empty values for other ids.
Is there a way to update the multiple top news based on the selection of multiple categories?

```
    /*Code for Radio Button*/

<label>Top News</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="topnews[]" value="1" id="topnews_0"  <?php echo($topnews=='1')?'checked':' '?> />Yes</label>
<label>
    <input name="topnews[]" type="radio" id="topnews_1" value="0" <?php echo($topnews=='0')?'checked':' '?> />No</label>
```

Comment: Radio buttons are for exaclty one selection, checkbox for multiple selections. They are different types in HTML! So make yourself clear if you use the right input type at the right place. Furthermore I don't understand your question totally - maybe you should edit it to make your problem more clearer by adding the expected and actual behavior

Comment: Has the problem anything to do with SQL at all? If not, please remove that part and show only the actual problem.

Comment: The sql returns the saved values of radio box, text, textarea, dropdown from the database while editing. The code is working well for rest of the field except radio button, so I am showing code for radio button only and not of all the field